# Laravel Routes not working 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel

I change my pc and install lamp on Windows 10 WSL.The main index works / but the routes is not. Here is my virtual host file.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/devroot/lara/panel/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "/var/www/devroot/lara/panel/public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And Here is the htaccess from project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The Error when i access a route link.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /lara/panel/public/admin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: did you check, you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in apache ?

Comment: Just guessing but 127.0.0.2 is not local host.

Comment: Can you post your `routes/web.php`?

Comment: Yes, i have mod_rewrite a2enmod rewrite, i made from hosts file new domain. 127.0.0.2 lara

Comment: When i access lara/ in url it works but the routes don't.

Comment: I'd try with a plain index.html in a different folder to pinpoint the problem

Comment: Nice point Enrico i try http://lara/test/index.html same problem maybe some permision on folder ?

Comment: are you missing `ServerName lara` in your vhost conf ?

Comment: i think yes wait to see

Comment: i put it but same :(

Comment: did you restart the web server ?

Comment: you post the error is `Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80` not lara

Comment: i take from local but same with lara The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at lara Port 80 it drive me crazy

Comment: Also make sure your `hosts` file (`system32\drivers\etc` or something, don't know the correct path) knows about the new ServerName

Comment: With php artisan serve it works it drive my crazzyyy

Comment: are you set `APP_URL = http://lara` in .env ? create a php_info.php to /admin, and try access by lara/admin/php_info.php

Comment: same don;t see the folder or the file

Comment: maybe your virtualhost settings incorrect, check again the document of your apache version

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the htaccess was hidden my bad i modified it to .htaccess from _htaccess and now it's working.

Answer (score -2):

Your VHost Settings are incorrect. Laravel default serves to `localhost:8000`. You see it as output after using `php artisan serve`. Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/devroot/lara/panel/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "/var/www/devroot/lara/panel/public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ok but i dont want php artisan serve i want in localhost lamp